# Why is w-fit making my navbar align to the left?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Im trying to centre my navbar which has a text logo and a logout button(hidden for current state). And i'm using a flex-col because I want my logout button and the logo to be vertically centered.
I also want to use a black background for the nav, but the problem is that it spans the whole page, and i want it to stick to the content.

on using w-fit, the navbar goes to the left

```
    <div className="app ">
      <div className='w-fit'>
        <nav className="main-nav flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-24 bg-[#0D0D0D] p-12 rounded-full ">
        <Link to="/"><h1 className=' text-3xl font-display text-[#F2F2F2] p-12'>text-logo</h1></Link>
          {this.state.user &&
            <a href='#!' onClick={this.logOutUser}>Log out</a>
          }
          
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pages displayed with left-to-right languages, such as English, elements will generally left align. As per [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content), (emphasis mine):

> The `fit-content` behaves as `fit-content(stretch)`. In practice this means that the box will use the available space, but **never more than `max-content`**.

Hence the `<div>` is left-aligned (as the default) with the content centered within. If you would like the `<div>` itself centered also, consider applying `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` to it via the `mx-auto` class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="app">
  <div class='w-fit mx-auto'>
    <nav class="main-nav flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-24 bg-[#0D0D0D] p-12 rounded-full ">
      <a to="/">
        <h1 class=' text-3xl font-display text-[#F2F2F2] p-12'>text-logo</h1>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
```